# How to encrypt POST Header on HTTP

Tags: post, encryption, https, secure-coding

Currently I am trying to encrypt POST headers on HTTP requests, the reason I am trying to do this is because my company handles critical process and we recently found that passwords were obtained using Firebug on Firefox on our customers computers (obtaining the POST header and stealing every password we put as a control)

Is there a good library that encrypts POST headers? if not, how can we get to that level of protection in those headers? Note: We can't use Self-Signed certificates due to the risks associated with them

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS.  It will encrypt everything, and is far more likely to be secure than any encryption scheme you try to hack together on your own.